# Is there a way to add the "select all" option in the multiselect widget of python's streamlit package?

Tags: python, multi-select, streamlit

I’m developing a `streamlit` app which contains a multiselect widget with 10 options. Is there an alternative to add a button that selects all the options to avoid selecting them one by one?

I tried adding a previous button to the multiselect, but using another widget resets the selection. Here is an example code:

```
import streamlit as st

if st.sidebar.button('Add all years'):
    year_filter = st.sidebar.multiselect('Select a year',[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004], default=[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004])
else:
    year_filter = st.sidebar.multiselect('Select a year',[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004], default=[2000])

type_filter = st.sidebar.multiselect('Choose a type',['Control','Experimental'], default=['Experimental'])

st.write(year_filter, type_filter)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way using the `state`:

```py
import streamlit as st
from streamlit.ReportThread import get_report_ctx
from streamlit.hashing import _CodeHasher
from streamlit.server.Server import Server


class _SessionState:
    def __init__(self, session, hash_funcs):
        """Initialize SessionState instance."""
        self.__dict__["_state"] = {
            "data": {},
            "hash": None,
            "hasher": _CodeHasher(hash_funcs),
            "is_rerun": False,
            "session": session,
        }

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        """Initialize state data once."""
        for item, value in kwargs.items():
            if item not in self._state["data"]:
                self._state["data"][item] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """Return a saved state value, None if item is undefined."""
        return self._state["data"].get(item, None)
        
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """Return a saved state value, None if item is undefined."""
        return self._state["data"].get(item, None)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        """Set state value."""
        self._state["data"][item] = value

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        """Set state value."""
        self._state["data"][item] = value
    
    def clear(self):
        """Clear session state and request a rerun."""
        self._state["data"].clear()
        self._state["session"].request_rerun()
    
    def sync(self):
        """Rerun the app with all state values up to date from the beginning to fix rollbacks."""

        # Ensure to rerun only once to avoid infinite loops
        # caused by a constantly changing state value at each run.
        #
        # Example: state.value += 1
        if self._state["is_rerun"]:
            self._state["is_rerun"] = False
        
        elif self._state["hash"] is not None:
            if self._state["hash"] != self._state["hasher"].to_bytes(self._state["data"], None):
                self._state["is_rerun"] = True
                self._state["session"].request_rerun()

        self._state["hash"] = self._state["hasher"].to_bytes(self._state["data"], None)


def _get_session():
    session_id = get_report_ctx().session_id
    session_info = Server.get_current()._get_session_info(session_id)

    if session_info is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Couldn't get your Streamlit Session object.")
    
    return session_info.session


def _get_state(hash_funcs=None):
    session = _get_session()

    if not hasattr(session, "_custom_session_state"):
        session._custom_session_state = _SessionState(session, hash_funcs)

    return session._custom_session_state


def main():
    state = _get_state()

    if state.previous_years_selected is None:
        state.previous_years_selected = [2000]
    
    if st.sidebar.button('Add all years'):
        year_filter = st.sidebar.multiselect('Select a year', [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004], default=[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004])
    else:
        year_filter = st.sidebar.multiselect('Select a year', [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004], default=state.previous_years_selected)

    # The next default (in case no one clicks on "Add all years")
    # will be the current years selected
    state.previous_years_selected = year_filter

    state.sync()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `_StateSession` object keeps data across Streamlit's reloads, meaning that if you interact a widget, the page reloads but the `state` keeps the information.
Here, we keep the information about the years that were selected during the last interaction with the "year selector" and provide it as a default for next reload (`default=state.previous_years_selected`).

You can add whatever data you want to the `state` object. Just make sure it does exist before modifying it:

```py
if state.previous_years_selected is None:
    state.previous_years_selected = [2000]
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks! I just needed to adapt the imports to make it work under streamlit 0.72:
`from streamlit.server.server import Server`

`from streamlit.report_thread import get_report_ctx`